# Extent Report: Not able to see the screenshots on other machine (C#-NUnit)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am able generate the extent reports with screenshots on my local machine. But when i mail the reports to someone else, or open the html on a different machine, the screenshots are not visible. It says that the path is invalid.

While attaching the screenshot, i am giving the path of my local machine. And it is searching the same path on other machine too. I tried zipping the html and pics in one folder too.

Please help me how to attach the screenshots into html file without local machine dependency.

I found solution for the same problem using Java-TestNG combination but unable to find the same in C#-NUnits.

Comment: I think this link would help you : https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/468

Comment: Hi Purendra  : - Thanks for you help , in the above link I am able to java solutions only. I am specifically looking for C# solutions.